# How to convert string to int into mips cutting through the blanks

Tags: assembly, mips

I write mips code.

```
.data
  string:
    .space 512
  
    
 newLine:
    .asciiz "\n"

.text

    la $a0, string
    li $a1, 512              # load 16 as max length to read into $a1
    li $v0,8                # 8 is string system call
    syscall
    
    la $t0, string 
    
    
loopSecondOnePart:
        lb   $a0,0($t0)
        beqz $a0,exitT2
        beq $a0,32,skipThisSpace
        beq $a0,10,skipThisSpace
        subi $a0,$a0,48
        
    li $v0,1
    syscall
    la $a0, newLine
    li $v0,4
    syscall
    
 skipThisSpace:
        addi $t0,$t0,1
    j  loopSecondOnePart
    
  exitT2:
    li $v0, 10           
    syscall
```

I read them byte one byte

for example, when i write such a string 21 4 3 1 23 43
I reached first 2 and then 2 and then 4 so on
I want to achive first 21 then 2 then so on.

I am planing to push to array to countinue my project.
I would be glad if you help

Comment: The standard algorithm for multi-digit numbers is `total = total*10 + digit`, starting with total=0. You're already detecting whitespace, so treat it as the end of one number, start of a possible next number.

Comment: Most algorithms are language independent, so you can search for and study "atoi" or "string to integer", in a language like C to see how they work end-to-end.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you so much. I sent a better assignment because of you.